# How do I find out how my currently Linux kernel was configured

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm getting no core dumps, and [core(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/core) says the problem might be that my kernel might be configured with `CONFIG_COREDUMP`, how do I find out if it is true?

I'm on Mint 17.3 (`uname -a`: `Linux laptop 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

Comment: What is your distribution and release version, please? In Debian and its derivatives, you can find the config file in `/boot`, called something like `config-kernel_version`.

Comment: If you're using Red Hat family (Red Hat, Fedora, CentOS) or Debian, there're config files in `/boot` directory.  `grep CONFIG_COREDUMP /boot/config-4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64` --> `CONFIG_COREDUMP=y`

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 Thanks. `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` does give me the info. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mint, you'll find the kernel configuration in `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`:

```
grep CONFIG_COREDUMP /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

Most distributions ship the kernel configuration in `/boot` nowadays.